# show/hide information jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I display the information  when the cooresponding header element is clicked? I am trying to use a div tag to hold the information and i'm unsure how to display it when clicked.  In this case click the pizza header and display info within pizza div. I am new to jQuery and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
<h2>Pizza</h2>
<h2>Sandwiches</h2>
<h2>Other Items</h2>
<h2>Beverages</h2>

<br>

 <div id="pizza">
 <h3>PIZZA <span class="tab"></span> 10" &nbsp; 12" &nbsp; 14"</h3>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <p>
 <strong>Classic:</strong>
 Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Palace:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms 
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Philly Steak:</strong>
 Seasoned Steak with Onions, Green Peppers on our
 Special White Sauce
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>"B" Special:</strong>
 Sausage, Salami, Canadian Bacon & Onions
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Maverick:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Canadian Bacon & Pepperoni
 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="sandwich">



 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){  
 $("h2").toggle();      
 });
 });
```

Comment: you need to redefine your selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working snippet below.

I added the data-type attribute to your h2 tags so that the script knows which div id to target.  The data-type attribute must match the id you are trying to display.

This script will apply an onclick event to ALL of your h2 tags instead of having to manually apply it to each one individually.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-type");
    $(".hidden").hide();
    $("#"+id+"").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 data-type="pizza">Pizza</h2>
<h2 data-type="sandwich">Sandwiches</h2>
<h2 data-type="other">Other Items</h2>
<h2 data-type="beverage">Beverages</h2>

<div id="pizza" class="hidden">
    <h3>PIZZA <span class="tab"></span> 10" &nbsp; 12" &nbsp; 14"</h3>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Classic:</strong>Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms</p>
    <p><strong>Palace:</strong>Sausage, Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms</p>
    <p><strong>Philly Steak:</strong>Seasoned Steak with Onions, Green Peppers on our Special White Sauce</p>
    <p><strong>"B" Special:</strong>Sausage, Salami, Canadian Bacon & Onions</p>
    <p><strong>Maverick:</strong>Sausage, Beef, Canadian Bacon & Pepperoni</p>
</div>
<div id="sandwich" class="hidden">Sandwiches</div>
<div id="other" class="hidden">Other</div>
<div id="beverage" class="hidden">Beverages</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me but here is a fiddle that does work https://jsfiddle.net/19q2696r/.  I like the way this answer matches `id` and `data-type` to make the code more elegant - my approach is pretty brute force.

Comment: Just finished appending an edit to my answer, and see that we wrote almost the same thing. :)

Comment: @ryebread - I was about to say... looked like you repurposed my script after the fact :)

Comment: @steveklein - You were doing too much work.  I've updated the answer with your code from jsfiddle.  All you needed to do was swap the h2 id's with the data-type attributes and use my original function.  The new snippet will show it in action.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help! Steve klein, ryebread, xengravity all your answers were great. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

## Good:

To solve your problem very simply, you just need to give your element an `id`, then reference that from your script:

**HTML**

```
<h2 id="showPizza">Pizza</h2>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#showPizza').click(function(){
    $('#pizza').toggle();
  });
})
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#showPizza').click(function(){
    $('#pizza').toggle();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="showPizza">Pizza</h2>
<h2>Sandwiches</h2>
<h2>Other Items</h2>
<h2>Beverages</h2>

<br>

 <div id="pizza" style="display:none;">
 <h3>PIZZA <span class="tab"></span> 10" &nbsp; 12" &nbsp; 14"</h3>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <p>
 <strong>Classic:</strong>
 Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Palace:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms 
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Philly Steak:</strong>
 Seasoned Steak with Onions, Green Peppers on our
 Special White Sauce
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>"B" Special:</strong>
 Sausage, Salami, Canadian Bacon & Onions
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Maverick:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Canadian Bacon & Pepperoni
 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="sandwich">
```

---

## Better

Even cleaner, is to add a `data` attribute, and then matching that in your code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    var elem_id = '#' + $(this).attr("data-toggle");
    $(elem_id).toggle();
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="toggle" data-toggle="pizza">Pizza</h2>
<h2 class="toggle" data-toggle="sandwich">Sandwiches</h2>

<div id="pizza" class="hidden">
 <h3>PIZZA <span class="tab"></span> 10" &nbsp; 12" &nbsp; 14"</h3>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <p>
 <strong>Classic:</strong>
 Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Palace:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Pepperoni, Onions & Mushrooms 
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Philly Steak:</strong>
 Seasoned Steak with Onions, Green Peppers on our
 Special White Sauce
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>"B" Special:</strong>
 Sausage, Salami, Canadian Bacon & Onions
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>Maverick:</strong>
 Sausage, Beef, Canadian Bacon & Pepperoni
 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="sandwich" class="hidden">
next div...
</div>
```